# Rangeslider is not working while I append it from one div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Hello, here I attach my code. look](http://tpcg.io/Rx1sOM)

I am trying to append range slider from one div to another div but its get me error. let me know where I make mistake.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is 404 errors for loading jquery resources. I've changed it to http protocol.
Next, you need to wrap your click event within document.ready function, because ".click_on" element is not visible at the start time.

Here is the link of fixed version of your code: http://tpcg.io/GBnoLR